# JSPDF adding a black background to converted PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

When I use JSPDF to convert from a PNG to PDF, wherever the PNG is transparent, JSPDF puts a black background in. Where can I find the code in the library to change this from black to white?

I am open to suggestions other than updating the library.

Comment: jspdf converts transparency into black.  so if you can set a background color to white you will be all set.  I'm not sure how you are sending you're png to jspdf but can you wrap it in a white div.  or if you use imagemagic `$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');`  I'm sure there must be an equivalent

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using before I drew the image to the canvas.

```
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
```